# Casper: Getting error Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Trying to click on a link using the below code. i am getting error at the 
code `this.click('/login')` help me solve this to be able to click on this link
I am struck.

I get the output as :

```
FAIL Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: /login
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: loki1.js:1355
```

Here is my code:

```
casper.test.begin('Signin to loki',1,function(test){


     casper.start('http://localhost:3000');

     casper.evaluate(function() {
       __utils__.echo("Hello World!");
  });

casper.wait(100,function(){
    casper.echo("Debuging");
    casper.echo("this:"+this);
    casper.echo("Done");



    if (this.exists('headerwrap')) {

    casper.echo('the heading exists');
}
this.click('/login');  ////This is not working

    this.fill('#loginForm', {
        'login' : 'Divya',
        'password' : '********'

}, false);
```

This is the html

What selector should i use to click on the a `href=/login`

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="main-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
             <a href="/login" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Login">Sign In</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please help me with this i also find problems in finding form elements i the login page.

Comment: <form id="#loginForm" class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST" action="/login">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="login" class="form-control" placeholder="CEC Userid" required="" autofocus="">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do this I believe. You could use jQuery to click on it, you could get the href and then open the page with that href, or you need to change the value inside the click.

## jQuery .click() and .prop()

To click with jQuery you could do something like this:

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
     jQuery('.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a').click()
});
```

you could also get the href from the html like so:

```
var link = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return jQuery('.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a').prop('href');
});
```

this will return the '/login' and with that you could do a `casper.thenOpen((your url)+link))`

## casper.click()

I think you need a different value inside your this.click(); I believe you would need something like this `this.click('#main-navbar-collapse > ul > li > a');` Some of this may need to be changed based on the html you have elsewhere, but this should hopefully help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you thaty works, Also i have one more thing for the form i am trying to fill the form like this. This is not working

Comment: this.fill('form##loginForm', {
             'redirect' : '/model',
   'login' : 'dnanjund',
   'password' : 'Praveen11!',
   ''

  }, true);

Comment: <form id="#loginForm" class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST" action="/login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/model"/>
<h4 class="form-signin-heading" align="center">Sign in with your Cisco Account</h4>

Comment: <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="login" class="form-control" placeholder="CEC Userid" required="" autofocus=""/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required=""/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="remember-me"/>
Remember me
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-footer form-group">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
</div>
</form>

Comment: It looks like you might want to use a 'this.sendKeys('selector', "String you want to input");' function.